# I can not see Azure Mobile App Template in ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create backend for Xamarin Forms following this article: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter1/firstapp_pc/#the-mobile-backend. In the article the author is creating a new ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework) which has Azure Mobile App template as an option to pick:

[image].

When I try to recreate the same project I am not seeing the same amount of templates in Visual Studio 2019 :

[image]

1. Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.10.4
2. Visual Studio Installer:

- Azure Development is installed.
- ASP.NET and Web Development is installed
- Mobile Development with .NET (Xamarin Development).

Is there any change to the Azure Mobile template in ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework) and if so what can be used as a replacement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile App project template for creating Xamarin [Backend is not available](https://vsf-prod.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/583370/missing-azure-mobile-app-project-template-in-visua.html) in Visual Studio 2019 16.1.1.

It was previously available in Visual Studio 2017 via
Templates > Visual C# > Cloud > ASP. NET Web Application (.NET Framework) > Azure Mobile App.

you can follow this updated [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/overview) for more information.